# MacBook Pro is constantly in kernel panic, freezing or entering restart loop

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

2018 MacBook Pro 15” model a1990 Is shutting off by itself. Fans run at full speed and it turns off. Some times I am able to login for a minute at most, other times it enters a infinite restart loop. Recovery mode results in a error (-1008F) holding D for diagnosis says there’s no hardware issue. I’ve tried all the different boot commands with mixed results, as I said there’s times where I can get into the computer and everything I previously had open is there and accessible but shortly after it will turn off. (Kernel panic?)

I was able to pull this on one of the restarts

```
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff80190689ca): Kernel trap at 0xffffff81e85a3520, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff81e85a3520, CR3: 0x00000001ef8de011, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff804b0f4000, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000017
RSP: 0xffffff81e85a3520, RBP: 0xffffff81e85a3520, RSI: 0x0000000000000017, RDI: 0xffffff804b0f4000
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0xffffff7f9c5dbd28, R10: 0xffffff7f9c5dbe6c, R11: 0x0000000010000003
R12: 0xffffff804b155660, R13: 0x0000000000000016, R14: 0x000000000000001f, R15: 0xffffff804bf4935b
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff81e85a3520, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff81e85a3520, Error code: 0x0000000000000011, Fault CPU: 0x4 Kernel NX fault, PL: 0, VF: 2

Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81e85a2f80 : 0xffffff8018f3f98b 
0xffffff81e85a2fd0 : 0xffffff8019076c15 
0xffffff81e85a3010 : 0xffffff801906861e 
0xffffff81e85a3060 : 0xffffff8018ee6a40 
0xffffff81e85a3080 : 0xffffff8018f3f077 
0xffffff81e85a3180 : 0xffffff8018f3f45b 
0xffffff81e85a31d0 : 0xffffff80196d2d89 
0xffffff81e85a3240 : 0xffffff80190689ca 
0xffffff81e85a33c0 : 0xffffff80190686c8 
0xffffff81e85a3410 : 0xffffff8018ee6a40 
0xffffff81e85a3430 : 0xffffff81e85a3520 
0xffffff81e85a3520 : 0xffffff7f9c5dbefa 
0xffffff81e85a3560 : 0xffffff7f9c603a44 
0xffffff81e85a35e0 : 0xffffff7f9c60af0b 
0xffffff81e85a36b0 : 0xffffff7f9c5f85b1 
0xffffff81e85a36e0 : 0xffffff7f9c5db152 
0xffffff81e85a3750 : 0xffffff7f9c5db071 
0xffffff81e85a37b0 : 0xffffff7f9c594f2a 
0xffffff81e85a3870 : 0xffffff7f9c594633 
0xffffff81e85a3900 : 0xffffff80191cb82e 
0xffffff81e85a3980 : 0xffffff80191c0fac 
0xffffff81e85a3b80 : 0xffffff80191c14bf 
0xffffff81e85a3bd0 : 0xffffff80191ae7cd 
0xffffff81e85a3f10 : 0xffffff80191aef7f 
0xffffff81e85a3f40 : 0xffffff801959b999 
0xffffff81e85a3fa0 : 0xffffff8018ee7206 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.apfs(1412.11.7)[B26D7DE6-BE2D-3E44-B334-1346AEC6C3BB]@0xffffff7f9c55a000->0xffffff7f9c67efff
            dependency: com.apple.kec.corecrypto(1.0)[263BCEB0-E4C5-3540-9E03-CC1F0A4D5BDF]@0xffffff7f99e32000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage(1.0)[D4D0276C-28F7-3878-AC53-86A1134225E0]@0xffffff7f99d8e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[CAC103D2-4533-3A81-8190-D0133B4F8626]@0xffffff7f99b75000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: xpcproxy
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19A603

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Wed Sep 25 20:18:50 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.11.26~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 70EDD61F-86EE-3E1B-873F-98D909B78160
Kernel slide:     0x0000000018c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8018e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8018d00000
System model name: MacBookPro15,1 (Mac-937A206F2EE63C01)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 4668631807
last loaded kext at 1396725744: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f99aef000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
>usb.realtek8153patcher 5.0.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.11.7
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    302
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.5.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.5
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.11.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   800.14
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.0f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.0f8
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.11.2
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0!
```

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Recovery mode (booting the installer) fails too?  Can you boot an Ubuntu media (usb/dvd)?

Comment: I tried booting from an external drive with same issue. Although last night I noticed if the machines battery is below 5% it would not go into restart loop. I was able to login but if it was plugged into power it would turn off as soon as battery reached a certain %.

Comment: Battery might be broken then.  Sounds like it might be a good idea to have a qualified mechanic have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks , i also found out unplugging battery allows for the machine to function 100% normally but as soon as I plug it back in issues persist

Comment: Sounds like you need a new battery.  Consider buying an original part.

Comment: I don't think it's your battery, but the logic board.  Why?  There is circuitry that "manages" where the power comes from - battery or mains.  If hooking up your battery causes kernel panics, there's something wrong with that circuitry because regardless of how much power your battery has, it "smooths" it out so it's useful to the CPU, memory, etc.

Comment: Also, I know it is obvious, since it's always the second thing suggested (after zapping the PRAM), but try resetting the SMC.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the symptoms only show when the battery is present in the computer.

That would indicate that the small computer in the battery is no longer behaving as expected by the Mac.  I would suggest trying a new, original battery.